# Logic error when getting output from encrypting string program.

Tags: c++, visual-studio, encryption, logic

I have made a program that takes a string into a class EncryptedString then encrypts said string removing anything that is not a space or a lower or uppercase letter. Everything seems to be working fine until I enter a string with something like 496496#@###!#!!!4 then it deletes some, and keeps others. I have some examples of what is supposed to be output.

- Input: Hello World!
- Expected Decrypted: Hello World
- Expected Encrypted: Ifmmp Xpsme
- Output Decrypted: Hello World
- Output Encrypted: Ifmmp Xpsme

Hello World works, just fine and deletes the !

However when I try to do "A apple ran away in autumn z!!14? I get this

- Input: A apple ran away in autumn z!!14?
- Expected Decrypted: A apple ran away in autumn z
- Expected Encrypted: B bqqmf sbo bxbz jo bvuvno a
- Output Decrypted: A apple ran away in autumn z 3
- Output Encrypted: B bqqmf sbo bxbz jo bvuvno a!4

And here is one more example.

- Input: Emily Dickinson1152163!!!@@#@#!!!
- Expected Decrypted: Emily Dickinson
- Expected Encrypted: Fnjmz Ejeljotpo
- Output Decrypted: Emily Dickinson015 ??
- Output Encrypted: Fnjmz Ejdljotpo126!!@@!!

I thought it may be that when I am iterating the code over decrypt.length() and enCry.length() it's going over the elements? However, I felt like it wasn't that as it's able to delete other numbers and symbols just fine but for some reason, some are staying. Is there something wrong with my code below during my iterations that can cause this?

```
    //This function takes the phrase,word or sentence and encrypts it, removing any illegal characters aside from ' ' and then proceeds to decrypt it then output them to the get functions. 
void EncryptedString::set(string str)
{
    char chBase = 'A';


    string enCry = str;
    for (int i = 0; i < enCry.length(); i++)
    {
        char ch = enCry[i];

        if (enCry[i] < chBase && enCry[i] != ' ')
        {
            enCry.erase(enCry.begin() + i);
        }
        else if (enCry[i] > chBase + 25 && enCry[i] < tolower(chBase) && enCry[i] != ' ')
        {
            enCry.erase(enCry.begin() + i);
        }
        else if (enCry[i] > tolower(chBase + 25) && enCry[i] != ' ')
        {
            enCry.erase(enCry.begin() + i);
        }
        else
        {
            if (enCry[i] == chBase + 25)
            {
                enCry[i] = 'A';
            }
            else if (enCry[i] == tolower(chBase) + 25)
            {
                enCry[i] = 'a';
            }
            else if (enCry[i] == ' ')
            {
                enCry[i] = ' ';
            }
            else
            { 
            enCry[i] = ch + 1;
            }

        }


    }

    EncryptedString::encryption = enCry;
    string decrypt = enCry;

    for (int i = 0; i < decrypt.length(); i++)
    {
        char ch = decrypt[i];

        if (decrypt[i] == 'A')
        {
            decrypt[i] = 'Z';
        }
        else if (decrypt[i] == 'a')
        {
            decrypt[i] = 'z';
        }
        else if (decrypt[i] == ' ')
        {
            decrypt[i] = ' ';
        }   
        else
        {
            decrypt[i] = ch - 1;
        }
    }

    decrypted = decrypt;
}


//This function outputs the decryption after the phrase was encrypted. 
const string EncryptedString::get()
{

    return decrypted;
}   
//This function outputs the encryption of the phrase. 
const string EncryptedString::getEncrypted()
{
    return EncryptedString::encryption;
}
```

As some more information here is what is in main.cpp where I am using these functions. I thought maybe it was because I was setting it twice in test2 but I tested test1 by adding numbers to hello world and that output just kept some of the numbers with it. If you need to see that example I will provide.

```
#include "EncryptedString.h"
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    cout << "TEST 1" << endl << endl;
    EncryptedString test1("Hello World!");
    cout << test1.get();
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << test1.getEncrypted();

    cout << endl << endl << "TEST 2" << endl << endl;


    EncryptedString test2;
    test2.set("A apple ran away in autumn z!!14?");
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << test2.get();
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << test2.getEncrypted();

    cout << endl << endl; 
    test2.set("Emily Dickson1152163!!!@@#@#!!!");
    cout << test2.get() << endl << endl << test2.getEncrypted();

    //being used for me to see the output. 
    Sleep(15000);
}
```

If someone can see where I went wrong or if maybe something is off with my iteration I'd be grateful. Thank anyone for reading all of this as I know it's probably a lot and thank you for any help that you can give me. Also would this be considered a logic error or structure error? I believe logic but I could be wrong and I would like to know so I don't make that mistake in the future when asking for help.

Comment: *If someone can see where I went wrong* -- Use the debugger that comes with your compiler to single-step through your program.

Comment: `str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), [](char ch){return !isalpha(ch) && !isspace(ch);}, str.end());` -- That one line removes all the illegal characters except for spaces.  In short, removes that entire block of code you wrote to do this.  The less code you need to write, the less mistakes you will make.

Comment: I'm using the debugger and I managed to fix two warnings that had to do with mismatched signs. Changing for(int i......) to for(size_t i......). However, still getting the same result. Is there any other way I can debug the program to get to the problem at hand or do I just need to look at something i've been overlooking?

Comment: I guess you did not use the debugger, but you think you did.  The debugger allows you to *run* your program, one statement at a time.  You can inspect variables, set breakpoints, see whether the program flows as you designed, etc.  What you described is what the *compiler* gives you as warnings.  Once the program has been built, the debugger allows you to run your program -- there is no need to think what you're program is doing, you can actually run it, one step at a time, and watch what it's doing.

Comment: Also, a revision: `str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), [](char ch){return (!isalpha(ch) && !isspace(ch)) || isdigit(ch);}, str.end());` -- That removes the digits also.  The issue seems to be that you failed to remove all the digits, but you need to see whether when you get to the second `for` loop, your string actually contains valid characters.  You could simply output exactly what you're trying to decrypt at that point as a debugging aide, even if you didn't know how to use the debugger.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ok, Thank you for your help again, today. I think I can manage on my own from here on. I will put in some outputs during the loop like you said. Thank you for helping me out. I guess I still have alot to learn when it comes to Visual studio's language and debugger.